# Changing config.xml in Sphinx4

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

I am running Transcriber demo in sphinx4 samples. But the accuracy is low. In Transcriber sources one of the html file says that this demo is for digits and to transcribe non digit data modify the config.xml. It says that "Please refer to the Programmer's Guide on how to modify the configuration file for your purposes." but i din't find any programmer's guide that i can modify config.xml.

Please tell me what changes i have to make that sphinx4 can be more accurate for non digit data Transcription.

Answer (score 0):

Recent transcriber source does not say anything about config.xml It is not recommended to change anything in config.xml, just use latest version sphinx4-5prealpha.

In order to get help on accuracy of transcription you need to provide more information on how you use sphinx4. You also need to provide the data you are trying to transcribe.

Comment: I want to do interview analysis and my target people are college students of universities in US so i want to convert their speech in to text and analyse that. I have downloaded clear US voice from youtube and and converted it in 16 bit 16kHZ wav file. I am using simple Transcriber demo example given in the documentation. Please tell me how can i improve the accuracy. I have also tried adaptation with 20 sentences.